# Sharepoint Search Service Crashed after patch KB956716

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Our networks guys installed this patch over the weekend to our single server sharepoint front end: KB956716

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a7fda284-273c-42ab-8188-433beaacca86&displaylang=en

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956716

After which our search service stopped working.

When attempting to do a search on any of our apps we get this error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: DisplayInAdminUI  (stack info below)

I logged into the shared services admin page and when I click on search settings it just crashes too.

I have included the event viewer error below as well...

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Christopher

---

Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category: Web Event 
Event ID:   1309
Date:       12/30/2008
Time:       1:03:35 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   VKSPS02
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 12/30/2008 1:03:35 PM 
Event time (UTC): 12/30/2008 7:03:35 PM 
Event ID: 90ade1cc6d5949a3ae2ea97afa5d75e6 
Event sequence: 19275 
Event occurrence: 67 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1927250994/Root-1-128751076993856152 
    Trust level: WSS_Minimal 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\vktoday80\ 
    Machine name: VKSPS02

Process information: 
    Process ID: 8136 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: VIRCHOWKRAUSE\SharePointSSPApp

Exception information: 
    Exception type: IndexOutOfRangeException 
    Exception message: DisplayInAdminUI

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://sitename.domain.net/searchcenter/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k=lori 
    Request path: /searchcenter/Pages/peopleresults.aspx 
    User host address: 172.30.202.56 
    User: VIRCHOWKRAUSE\JF11767 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: NTLM 
    Thread account name: DOMAINNAME\SharePointSSPApp

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 6 
    Thread account name: DOMAINNAME\SharePointSSPApp 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ConsumerScopeCache.Refresh()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ConsumerScopeCache.EnsureFresh()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ScopeCache.TryGetScope(Guid siteGuid, Int32 id, ScopeInformation& scope)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ScopeCache.TryGetSharedScope(Int32 id, ScopeInformation& scope)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnHiddenObject()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.PeopleCoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnHiddenObject()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.PeopleCoreResultsWebPart.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Custom event details:

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

---

### Server Error in '/' Application.

DisplayInAdminUI 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: DisplayInAdminUI

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[IndexOutOfRangeException: DisplayInAdminUI]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName) +1433771
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name) +102
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name) +12
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ConsumerScopeCache.Refresh() +1241
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ConsumerScopeCache.EnsureFresh() +58
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ScopeCache.TryGetScope(Guid siteGuid, Int32 id, ScopeInformation& scope) +75
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ScopeCache.TryGetSharedScope(Int32 id, ScopeInformation& scope) +68
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnHiddenObject() +2503
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.PeopleCoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnHiddenObject() +41
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +1977
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.PeopleCoreResultsWebPart.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +11
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +86
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +62
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +170
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +170
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +170
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +170
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +170
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2041

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar experience with a corrupt search index (caused by the indexing server randomly rebooting) and unfortunately the only way to fix it was to Stop the Search Services and Start them again. This is done through Central Admin-Operations-Topology and Services-Services on Servers.

Not that we were getting this error - the IndexOutOfRangeException error you are getting relates to something going out of the bounds of a list or something when displaying the UI rather than something to do with the search index. However, the behaviour you describe is the same as we were getting - searches returning errors and not being able to access the Search configuration area in the Shared Services Provider.

Note that this is not like stopping and starting a Windows service - stopping the search service uninstalls it from the indexing server and starting it re-installs it so you will lose your search index and will have to do a full crawl to get it back. So be very sure that you are out of other options and are willing to lose your search index before going down this path.

Answer (score 0):

Well I broke down and opened a support ticket w/ M$.  They did resolve the issue quite quickly.  We use lan desk to push our patches to our servers.  Our networks guys didn't run the sharepoint product config wizard after the patch was installed.  I guess this needs to be done on any update to the binaries which most of the patches do update..

So we ran the config wizard, it failed.  Then tries to run it using command line:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\BIN>PSCO
NFIG -CMD UPGRADE -INPLACE B2B -FORCE -WAIT

That failed too... but just on the last step of restarting the service (found that info in the log).  So we started the services manually, reset iis. and it WORKED!

I guess our network guys need to learn to run the Sharepoint Configuration Wixard or Psconfig at the command prompt.